# getting the output in reverse order for given java program

Tags: java, system.out

I ran the following java code on NetBeans IDE. First time I got the output as

```
aaaaaa aaaa
!
```

and when i ran the same code the second time I got the output as

```
!
aaaaaa aaaa
```

in reverse order...why?? for the same piece of code

```
public class check { 
    public String toString(){
        String hello="aaaaaa aaaa";       
        return hello;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        check obj=new check();
         char[] abc=new char[5];
        System.err.println(obj);
        String hello="heaa^qwertyui";
        hello.getChars(2, 3, abc, 0);
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
}
```

Comment: string in main function is    "he!@#$%^^qwertyui"   not    "heaa^qwertyui"

Answer (score 5):

You print to both `System.err` and `System.out`. These are different streams that happen to print to your console. The order in which they are flushed and the order in which their output appears can not be predicted.

Comment: `println` has an *implicit* `flush`.

Answer (score 0):

change  `System.err.println` to  `System.out.println`

```
public class check { 
    public String toString(){
        String hello="aaaaaa aaaa";       
        return hello;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        check obj=new check();
         char[] abc=new char[5];
        System.out.println(obj);
        String hello="heaa^qwertyui";
        hello.getChars(2, 3, abc, 0);
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
}
```